# Angular ng-repeat filtering by matching to another array's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-deployment

I am having a really hard time figuring out how to filter a scope object (row.matric && row.dimension) based on another scope object (metrics && dimension) by matching keys.

The code below is an example of the objects that i am using.

In the `ng-repeat="row in rows”` section; I need to only show the row.metric or row.dimention if and only if its partner metric or dimension has the key of `tabled` set to true.

row.metric and row.dimension are matched to metric and dimension by the key `key`.

For example: The row.metric ‘visits’ should be displayed, but ‘pageviews’ should not be displayed.

Here is a Plunker ( this this instead of the cod below ) the number 400 and 20 should NOT be displayed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/t15L5y40h8enPzUkkaJw?p=preview

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="dimension" ng-repeat="dimension in dimensions | filter:{tabled:true}" >{[{ dimension.name }]}</th>
            <th class="metric" ng-repeat="metric in metrics | filter:{tabled:true}" >{[{ metric.name }]}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td class="dimension" ng-repeat="dimension in row.dimensions" >{[{ dimension.value }]}</td>
            <td class="metric" ng-repeat="metric in row.metrics" >{[{ metric.current }]}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Objects:

```
metrics Example: [
    {
        name: 'Visits',
        key: 'visits',
        tabled: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Page Views',
        key: 'pageviews',
        tabled: fales
    }
]

dimension Example: [
    {
        name: 'Source',
        key:  'source'
        tabled: true
    },
    { ... }
]


row Example: {
    metrics: [
        {key: 'visits', current: '203'},
        {key: 'pageviews', current: '104'},
        {...}
    ]
    dimensions: [
        {key: 'source', value: 'google'},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Comment: hard to follow guidleines, `tabled` for `PageViews` is `true` so why would it not be shown? A live demo would help, perhaps also showing expected output as well

Comment: fixed, sorry it was `pageviews` is supposed to be false.  It is edited and fixed now.  @charlietfl

Comment: IFF === "if and only if" ... that being said i am writing a better description of the problem now and it will be updated in a ew minutes @Lucio

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve (and the question itself is full of typos which makesit even harder to follow). You should at least show what the expected output is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a custom filter, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOnHV6I6bx4a4XJxi0Yu?p=preview)

```
<td class="dimension" ng-repeat="dimension in row.dimensions | filter:isTabled(dimensions)">
<td class="metric" ng-repeat="metric in row.metrics| filter:isTabled(metrics)">

$scope.isTabled = function(list) {
  return function(item) {
    return list.some(function(matchingItem) {
      return item.key == matchingItem.key && matchingItem.tabled;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Answered in the #angularjs IRC.

Here is the plunker that resolved the issue. Note that this is probably not the most performant and recommendation is to refactor the data.

Uses ng-if with a scope function

```
  $scope.isTabled = function(key) {
    console.log(key);
    return _.find($scope.metrics,function(o){
      return o.key == key;
    }).tabled;
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tUNFx5uli4ABDQcpkUjx?p=preview

Comment: This is arguably a better solution than mine

Comment: Helped me resolve the key value from an API that returned list of results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386680/how-to-iterate-json-object-with-array-and-populate-table-using-angular-js/40387399#40387399   In this mockup question: the Continent key could be resolved with this answer.